# AWS Cognito group of user not showing

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have an AWS Cognito User pool with the group 'Admins'. The group has rights to everything.

I add the user to the group and check his groups ("cognito: groups"), but the user does not have a group.

Identity Pools is configured. Cognito with User Pool ID and App client id added to Authentication providers. The role is set as 'Choose role from token', Role resolution: DENY.

How to make the user display the group immediately? I need this to give permission  a specific Cognito group to the Gateway API.